# ¿como puedo ordenar de forma ascendente una tabla de posiciones almacenada en un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando un juego que demanda una tabla de posiciones, la cual está hecha de los nombres de usuarios ingresados y sus respectivos puntajes finales. Tengo dudas sobre como podría ordenar dichos datos sin que se desordenen entre sí, puesto qué ordenar la parte numérica es fácil, el problema para mi serían los nombres que concuerden con ese ordenamiento numérico. Por ahora tengo la función hecha así, no hay codigo de ordenamiento puesto que he mirado maneras de ordenar, pero todas me separarían los nombres de los puntajes y eso no es lo que busco.

La función agregar la llamo al final del juego. De antemano muchas gracias!

```
                            function agregar(){


                             persona=document.getElementById('nombre').value;// recibe el nombre ingresado desde otra funcion
                                if(persona==""){
                                    contj=contj+1;
                                    auxiliarPersona="Jugador "+contj;
                                    auxiliarPuntaje=contG;
                                           }
                                else{
                                auxiliarPuntaje=contG;
                                 auxiliarPersona=persona;
                                     }
                                tabla.push(auxiliarPersona,auxiliarPuntaje);
                                document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML=tabla;   
                            }
```

Comment: Por favor incluye un ejemplo de tu arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora tengo la función hecha así, no hay codigo de ordenamiento puesto que he mirado maneras de ordenar, pero todas me separarían los nombres de los puntajes y eso no es lo que busco.

La función agregar la llamo al final del juego. De antemano muchas gracias!

```
                        function agregar(){
                         persona=document.getElementById('nombre').value;// recibe el nombre ingresado desde otra funcion
                            if(persona==""){
                                contj=contj+1;
                                auxiliarPersona="Jugador "+contj;
                                auxiliarPuntaje=contG;
                                       }
                            else{
                            auxiliarPuntaje=contG;
                             auxiliarPersona=persona;
                                 }
                            tabla.push(auxiliarPersona,auxiliarPuntaje);
                            document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML=tabla;   
                        }
```